# Sorting int field of the wrapper class spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Navigation class where I am dynamically creating the navigation I am having two tables folder(it is directory that contains files) and content(it is like files or pages that will render the content on the public site). I have created a Navigation class in which I am having a wrapper class for merging the fields of content into the folder. I have tried using @OrderBy and @OrderColumn but I came to know that it will only work with collections.

`List<Folder> folder = folderRepository.findAllByNavDepthLessThanOrderByNavDepthAsc(3);`

here I am sorting it with navDepth(this column belongs to Folder entity) I also want to sort it with navOrder(this column belongs to Content entity)

```
@Service
public class NavigationService {

    @Qualifier("jdbcMySQL")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private FolderRepository folderRepository;
    private FolderService folderService;

    @Autowired
    public NavigationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, 
            FolderRepository folderRepository,
            FolderService folderService) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.folderRepository = folderRepository;
        this.folderService = folderService;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
    public Map<String, NavigationItem> navigationItems() {
        // TODO: // CROSS cutting AOP springs
        // TODO: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop
        List<Folder> folder = folderRepository.findAllByNavDepthLessThanOrderByNavDepthAsc(3);
        // List<Folder> folder = folderService.navigation();
        Map<String, NavigationItem> navItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, NavigationService.NavigationItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < folder.size(); i++) {
            NavigationItem ni = new NavigationItem();
            ni.setNavDepth((int) (folder.get(i).getNavDepth()));
            ni.setFileNamePath(folder.get(i).getDirectoryPath());
            ni.setFilepath(folder.get(i).getDirectoryPath());
            ni.setChildren(folder.get(i).getContent());
            for (int k = 0; k < folder.size(); k++) {
                if(folder.get(i).getId() == folder.get(k).getParentId()) {
                        ni.addSubFolder(folder.get(k));
                        System.out.println(folder.get(i).getTitle());
                        System.out.println(folder.get(k));
                        System.out.println("---!!!!!!________----------!!!!!!!!");
                }
            }
            navItems.put(folder.get(i).getTitle(), ni);
        }
        return navItems;
    }

    public class NavigationItem {
        private long id;
        private long parentId;
        private String title;
        private String fileName;
        private String fileNamePath;
        private int navDepth;
        private int navOrder;
        private String parentFileName;
        private String filePath;
        private String folderName;
        @OrderColumn(name="navOrder ASC")
        private List<Content> children = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList<Folder> subFolder = new ArrayList();


        public void setSubFolder(ArrayList<Folder> subFolder) {
            this.subFolder = subFolder;
        }
        public String getFilePath() {
            return filePath;
        }
        public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }
        public String getFolderName() {
            return folderName;
        }
        public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
            this.folderName = folderName;
        }
        public ArrayList<Folder> getSubFolder() {
            return subFolder;
        }
        public void addSubFolder(Folder subFolder) {
            this.subFolder.add(subFolder);
        }
        public void setChildren(List<Content> list) {
            this.children = list;
        }
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public long getParentId() {
            return parentId;
        }
        public void setParentId(long parentId) {
            this.parentId = parentId;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }
        public String getFileNamePath() {
            return fileNamePath;
        }
        public void setFileNamePath(String fileNamePath) {
            this.fileNamePath = fileNamePath;
        }
        public long getNavDepth() {
            return navDepth;
        }
        public void setNavDepth(int navDepth) {
            this.navDepth = navDepth;
        }
        public long getNavOrder() {
            return navOrder;
        }
        public void setNavOrder(int navOrder) {
            this.navOrder = navOrder;
        }
        public String getParentFileName() {
            return parentFileName;
        }
        public void setParentFileName(String parentFileName) {
            this.parentFileName = parentFileName;
        }
        public List<Content> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }
        public void addChild(Content child) {
            children.add(child);
        }
        public String getFilepath() {
            return filePath;
        }
        public void setFilepath(String filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but am I right that you want to sort  `NavigationItem` based on some value of the elements in the `children` list? If so, just write a comparator that selects the lowest/highest value of the children along with a special value when there are no children and compare those single values.

Comment: @Thomas - Yes I want to sort NavigationItem based on the value of element in the children list i,e, nav_order. Could you please explain it further ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Comparator<NavigationItem>` and pass that to `Collections.sort()` or similar methods.

The comparator might look like this:

```
class NavComparator implements Comparator<NavigationItem> {
  int specialValueNoChildren = -1; //assuming nav_order is always 0 or greater      

  int compare(NavigationItem o1, NavigationItem o2) {
    int max1 = getMaxNavOrder( o1 );
    int max2 = getMaxNavOrder( o2 );
    return Integer.compare( max1, max2 );
  }

  int getMaxNavOrder( NavigationItem ni ) {
    int max = specialValueNoChildren;
    for( Content child : ni.getChildren() ) {
      max = Math.max(max, child.getNavOrder());
    }

    return max;
  }
}
```

Here the maximum nav order of all children is selected with -1 being the special case of no children. Then the items are compared by their respective children's maximum nav order.

If you need a different order change that accordingly, e.g. by reversing `max1` and `max2` or by getting the lowest nav order of the children etc.

Comment: when I put this code under the Navigation service class getting error on line `int compare(NavigationItem o1, NavigationItem o2) ` saying change the visibility to public ?

Comment: @webgeek yeah most probably. The code above was meant as an example, not for copy-paste. Please adjust accordingly.